# Reference txt file from code in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have a very simple example in Scala for reading a text file. The example is made in IntelliJ. However when I try to use io.Source.fromFile("..\..\resources\example.txt"), I get a FileNotFoundException. The code works when I type in the absolute path.

Can anyone tell me how to use relative paths for specifying a file in Intellij project?

the directory structure:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paths are relative to the current/working directory, i.e. the directory from which the `java` command is executed.

When an application is executed from IntelliJ, this working directory is configured in the Run configuration used to launch the application.

So, go to *Run - Edit configurations...*, then find your run configuration, edit it, and see what the field "Working directory" contains. By default, the working directory is the root directory of the project.

Note that, unless the String escaping rules are different in Scala from Java, the path must be separated by slashes:

```
"../../resources/example.txt"
```

, or the backslashes must be escaped:

```
"..\\..\\resources\\example.txt"
```

Also not that if your goal is to bundle the text file inside the jar of your application, you shouldn't use file IO to read it, but use the `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()` method.

Comment: Scala's string escaping rules for double-quoted strings are identical to Java's. Alternatively, a triple-double-quoted string could be used, i.e., `"""..\..\resources\example.txt"""`.